# Run string through hashlib

Tags: python, hashlib

Lets say i have a string like:

```
string = '456878921'
```

I would like to run this string through every hashing type python can offer from some package (lets say hashlib), so ideally, solution for this problem would be something like:

```
hashes = ['md5', 'sha256']

for n in hashes:
    print(str(n) + ": " + str(hashlib.n(string).hexdigest())
```

Is this even possible in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
bytes = string.encode('utf-8') # hashlib algorithms require bytes!

for h in hashes:
    hash = getattr(hashlib, h)
    print(f'{h}: {hash(bytes).hexdigest()}')
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
import hashlib
hash_obj = hashlib.sha256(b'456878921')
hexing= hash_obj.hexdigest()
print(hexing)
```